# Header and footer with dotted lines

Tags: header-footer, scrlayer-scrpage

Our company has a new corporate design for documents, including headers and footers with dotted lines. I realised the desired layout, but it is kind of a quick and dirty solution. This is a minimal example:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[
a4paper,            % Papierformat
twoside,            % zweiseitiges Dokument
headings=SMALL,     % Größe der Überschriften verkleinern
headings=optiontohead, % ermöglicht Kurzüberschriften
DIV=15,             %
twocolumn=true,     %
headinclude=true,   %
final               % Status des Dokuments (final/draft)
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[german,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}% für Luatex benötigt
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[nochapter]{vhistory}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lastpage}

% Definition von Kopf- und Fußzeilen
\clearpairofpagestyles
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{\normalfont\fontsize{9.5pt}{11.4pt}\selectfont}
\ihead[Musterhandbuch der Musterfirma]{Musterhandbuch der Musterfirma}
\chead[\raisebox{-8mm}{\parbox{\textwidth+3pt}{\dotfill}}] 
{\raisebox{-8mm}{\parbox{\textwidth+3pt}{\dotfill}}}
\ohead[Version 2016-\vhCurrentVersion\\vom: \vhCurrentDate]{Version   
2016-\vhCurrentVersion\\vom: \vhCurrentDate}
\ofoot[{Seite \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}]{Seite \thepage/   
\pageref{LastPage}}
\cfoot[\parbox{13cm}{\dotfill}]{\parbox{13cm}{\dotfill}}
\refoot[\usebox{\Logo}]{\usebox{\Logo}}
\lofoot[\usebox{\Logo}]{\usebox{\Logo}}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\newsavebox{\Logo}
\savebox{\Logo}{\rule{1.8cm}{.7cm}}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\onecolumn
\cleardoublepage
\markboth{Versionshistorie}{Versionshistorie} 

{\textbf{\large\sffamily Versionshistorie}}
\label{historie}

\begin{versionhistory}
\vhEntry{1.0}{04.03.2016}{XY}{Version 2016 in Kraft gesetzt}
\end{versionhistory}

\end{document}
```

My questions are:

1. How can I change \headsepline into dotted line? My workaround has the disadvantage that I cannot use \chead for inserting text.
2. In the footer the dotted line has a fixed length. If I change the page layout by choosing another DIV-value, I manually have to adapt the length of the line. The line also did not have the same distance to the logo as to the pagenumber. How can I get an dotted line that fills the distance between logo and pagenumber?

Example with \headsepline:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[
a4paper,            % Papierformat
twoside,            % zweiseitiges Dokument
headings=SMALL,     % Größe der Überschriften verkleinern
headings=optiontohead, % ermöglicht Kurzüberschriften
DIV=15,             %
twocolumn=true,     %
headinclude=true,   %
final               % Status des Dokuments (final/draft)
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[german,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}% für Luatex benötigt
\usepackage[automark, headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[nochapter]{vhistory}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lastpage}

% Definition von Kopf- und Fußzeilen
\clearpairofpagestyles
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{\normalfont\fontsize{9.5pt}{11.4pt}\selectfont}
\ihead[Musterhandbuch der Musterfirma]{Musterhandbuch der Musterfirma}
%\chead[\raisebox{-8mm}{\parbox{\textwidth+3pt}{\dotfill}}]  
{\raisebox{-8mm}{\parbox{\textwidth+3pt}{\dotfill}}}
\ohead[Version 2016-\vhCurrentVersion\\vom: \vhCurrentDate]{Version  
2016-\vhCurrentVersion\\vom: \vhCurrentDate}
\ofoot[{Seite \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}]{Seite \thepage/     
\pageref{LastPage}}
\cfoot[\parbox{13cm}{\dotfill}]{\parbox{13cm}{\dotfill}}
\refoot[\usebox{\Logo}]{\usebox{\Logo}}
\lofoot[\usebox{\Logo}]{\usebox{\Logo}}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\newsavebox{\Logo}
\savebox{\Logo}{\rule{1.8cm}{.7cm}}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\onecolumn
\cleardoublepage
\markboth{Versionshistorie}{Versionshistorie} 

{\textbf{\large\sffamily Versionshistorie}}
\label{historie}

\begin{versionhistory}
\vhEntry{1.0}{04.03.2016}{XY}{Version 2016 in Kraft gesetzt}
\end{versionhistory}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A first try could be, to redefine `\headsepline`. i.e. `\renewcommand{\headsepline}{\dotfill}` and see, what happens. Do you have an example with \headsep, so we can simply copy it?

Comment: I tried to redefine \headsepline, but I got an error. Example with headsepline:

Comment: me too ;) . I haven't found anything in the KOMA-docu yet. But maybe, you like my attempt. I would package it into a macro, to make it look better.

Comment: thank you for your solution; there is no hint in the KOMA-book, too. I looked at the definition of scrlayer-scrpage inside the stylefile, but the definition of \headsepline seems to difficult to me. I hope that anyone knows how to redefine headsepline :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the layers `scrheadings.head.below.line` and `plain.scrheadings.head.below.line` to insert a dotted line on pages using one of the page styles `scrheadings` or `plain.scrheadings`. Note that `plain` is an alias for `plain.scrheadings`.

For the footer I would use `\cofoot` and `\cefoot`. The starred versions of this commands use the argument for both page style `scrheadings` and `plain.scrheadings`.

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,            % Papierformat
twoside,            % zweiseitiges Dokument
headings=small,     % Größe der Überschriften verkleinern
headings=optiontohead, % ermöglicht Kurzüberschriften
DIV=15,             %
twocolumn=true,     %
headinclude=true,   %
final,               % Status des Dokuments (final/draft)
footheight=20pt,
headheight=22.8pt
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[german,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}% für Luatex benötigt
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[nochapter]{vhistory}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lastpage}

% Definition von Kopf- und Fußzeilen
\clearpairofpagestyles
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\fontsize{9.5pt}{11.4pt}\selectfont}

\ModifyLayer[
  addvoffset=.8pt,
  contents={%
    \normalfont\usekomafont{pageheadfoot}\usekomafont{pagehead}%
    \usekomafont{headsepline}\dotfill
  }
]{scrheadings.head.below.line}
\RedeclareLayer[
  clone=scrheadings.head.below.line
]{plain.scrheadings.head.below.line}

\ihead*{Musterhandbuch der Musterfirma}
\chead[Text auf plain Seiten]{\headmark}
\ohead*{Version 2016-\vhCurrentVersion\\vom: \vhCurrentDate}

\renewcommand*\pagemark{%
  \usekomafont{pageheadfoot}Seite\ \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}%
}

\newsavebox{\Logo}
\savebox{\Logo}{\rule{1.8cm}{.7cm}}

\cofoot*{%
  \raisebox{-.5\height}{\usebox{\Logo}}%
  \qquad\dotfill\qquad%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height+.5\depth\relax}{\pagemark}%
}

\cefoot*{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height+.5\depth\relax}{\pagemark}%
  \qquad\dotfill\qquad%
  \raisebox{-.5\height}{\usebox{\Logo}}%
}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument

\onecolumn
\cleardoublepage
\addsec[tocentry={}]{Versionshistorie}
\label{historie}
\begin{versionhistory}
\vhEntry{1.0}{04.03.2016}{XY}{Version 2016 in Kraft gesetzt}
\end{versionhistory}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that value `SMALL` for `headings` does not exist. You have to use `small` or `normal` or `big`. I have enlarged `footheight` and `headheight` to avoid the warnings.

Comment: Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded with this solution. Works and solves no.1, but is dirty as well.

```
\chead{\parbox[c][16mm]{\textwidth+3pt}{\vspace*{12pt} \ \\ \centering{Text}}\\ {\parbox{\textwidth+3pt}{\dotfill}}
}
```

The hardcoded `\` prevents a no-line-to-end-error.